# How to update pagination action in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

In angular app, I have used `ng2-smart-table`. And I have enable pagination in that. But it shows normal look. Instead of that default look, I have used dropdown with page option.

```
<select>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>10</option>   
  <option>15</option>
</select>
```

I have set change event also.

Issues:

1) How can I update `ng2-smart-table` to set page size as per value change.

2) I want to also move on specific page. E.x: Table has 1000 data and per pager there are 10 records. So I want to just on page of `14`. So, how can I do that?

For that, I have refer it's documentation but I didn't get any event for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update perpage value.

```
this.DataSource.getPaging().perPage = event.target.value;
```

And to set a specific page you have to use `setPage()`.

```
this.DataSource.setPage(3); // Pass page number
```

It works fine for me. for details example please see this [link.](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/ng2-smart-table/components/pager/pager.component.ts)

Comment: DataSource.setPaging() worked for me. setPage() did not work for me.

Comment: @blogs4t I don't know why ? I think you might be doing in diffrent way. But for me it always works.

Comment: setPaging() is for number of rows per page and setPage() is for current page-> this is mostly used for pagination if you directly jump to specific page.